# Triming within a filter method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to remove trailing spaces from a phrase as I am filtering my data but the `trim()` method doesn't seem to be removing the spaces as expected if I try and mutate the data within the filter method.

Here is my code:

```
{item.fields
       .filter(item =>item.text.trim() === description)
       .map((field, i) => {
       return (<div></div>)
})}
```

Any idea why the `trim()` method wouldn't work?

Comment: can you add sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 1):

(I assume `item` in your `filter` callback should be `field`. Technically doesn't matter, but much easier to read.)

> ...if I try and mutate the data within the filter method...

The `trim` call works, but then you're not keeping the result for anything. You're not mutating the data. You only used it temporarily when doing the `===`.

You could trim again in the `map` callback:

```
{item.fields
    .filter(field => field.text.trim() === description)
    .map((field, i) => {
        return <div>{field.text.trim()}</div>; // <===
    })
}
```

Or you could make your `filter` callback do double-duty, trimming the field *and* doing the comparison. Those kinds of side-effects in `filter` callbacks are often considered poor practice, though:

```
{item.fields
    .filter(field => {
        field.text = field.text(); // Side effect, often considered poor practice
        return field.text === description;
    })
    .map((field, i) => {
        return <div>{field.text}</div>;
    })
}
```

Or when you receive `item.fields`, you could trim them once so you don't have to do it on every render.

Comment: Instead of the side effect variant there is also the option to `map()` beforehand, to transform the data in the desired format. `item.fields.map(field => ({ ...field, text: field.text.trim() })).filter(field => field.text === description).map(field => <div>{field.text}</div>)`

Comment: @3limin4t0r - I thought I mentioned that, but it looks like instead I suggested just doing that once up front rather than every time: *"Or when you receive item.fields, you could trim them once so you don't have to do it on every render."*